# PHP - заменить в файле символы в определенной позиции

Tags: php, файлы

Задача: заменить три символа подряд в файле, положение которых начинается с позиции N.
Долго искал решение и все время оно сводилось к тому, чтобы прочитать файл и поместить в переменную в виде строки. Затем найти нужный участок или положение, изменить переменную и перезаписать файл. Но если файл получается в 10т символов и происходят очень частые точечные изменения, то получается, как мне кажется, большая нагрузка (как минимум излишняя). Попытался сделать другое решение - используя fseek() нахожу нужное положение в открытом файле, но не знаю, как можно заменить следующие 3 символа. Если использовать fwrite(), то символы будут добавлены, а не заменены.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы все делаете **правильно**, но главное, поставить правильный режим при использовании функции **fopen**. Конечно, файл будет дописан данными, если вы поставите режим **a** (или **a+**), которые передвигают указатель в конец.

Если вы поставите режим **w** или **w+**, то по сути вы перезапишите весь файл, т.к. данный режим обрезает файл до нулевой длины. А вот использование режима **с**, **с+** или **r+** нам подходит, т.к. они работают с текущим файлом и его данными, перемещая указатель в самое начало и не обрезая файл.

Алгоритм прост: открываете файл, перемещаете указатель на нужное кол-во байт, записываете с этой позиции нужное кол-во символов и закрываете указатель.

```
$file = fopen("text.txt", "c"); //открываем файл с режимом c
fseek($file, 3); //перемещаем указатель (0 - это начало файла)
fwrite($file, "www"); //пишем по указателю свои данные
fclose($file); //закрываем файл
```

Если у меня был файл с содержимым '**wwwttt.ru**', то после выполнения скрипта файл будет содержать '**wwwwww.ru**', т.к. мы сместили указатель на 3 байта и поместили его перед t, а потом выполнили запись своих 3 символов, которые заменили существующие.

Кстати, если вы хотите написать данную операцию в стиле ООП, можете использовать встроенный **SplFileObject**

```
$file = new SplFileObject('text.txt', 'c');
$file->fseek(3);  
$file->fwrite("www");
$file = null; //close file
```